# How to parse curl to JSON?

Tags: php, json, curl

I am new in using curl, and I don't know how to parse this link to JSON:

```
    curl --get --include 'https://doodle-manga-
    scraper.p.mashape.com/mangafox.me/manga/naruto/1' \
    -H 'X-Mashape-Key: LhdkCyyF6Tmsh3BXTnN79quTbg08p1j2B20jsn89wOXridOzNe' \
     -H 'Accept: text/plain'
```

I do have this PHP script:

```
     $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
       CURLOPT_URL => 'https://doodle-manga-
    scraper.p.mashape.com/mangafox.me/manga/naruto/1'
        ));
```

I never used curl. How can I use PHP to parse data from the command above?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a community of volunteers offering aid to programmers stuck on a particular task. We are **not** a service to write free code for you. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AlexHowansky, i am sorry and i kknow that. I am actually a student in informatic, and i really don t know what to do for this.
I know that Stack Overflow! We are a community of volunteers offering aid to programmers stuck on a particular task. but i am really stuck at this,

Answer (score 0):

We are talking about parsing the response, yea? You will need to have python installed, but this has worked for me:

```
| python -m json.tool
```

Place it at the end of your statement. So yours would look like:

```
curl --get --include 'https://doodle-manga-
scraper.p.mashape.com/mangafox.me/manga/naruto/1' \
-H 'X-Mashape-Key: LhdkCyyF6Tmsh3BXTnN79quTbg08p1j2B20jsn89wOXridOzNe' \
 -H 'Accept: text/plain' | python -m json.tool
```

Comment: actually i am trying to right a php script that parse the data from this curl command. I really don t understand a thing in curl and i need to finish this thing for after tommorow :(.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $post = array('X-Mashape-Key' =>'LhdkCyyF6Tmsh3BXTnN79quTbg08p1j2B20jsn89wOXridOzNe' , 'Accept' => 'text/plain');
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://doodle-manga-scraper.p.mashape.com/mangafox.me/manga/naruto/1');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, True);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $jsonresult = json_decode($result);
```

This should be it